# Tensorflow Python: Finished Training DNN Regression Model, predictions wildly vary when executing multiple times

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using Tensorflow Python, and I am using the DNN Regression Model, to train over some Abalone data. (https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Abalone)

Also to make sure it's clear, I am using Jupyter, so I am essentially programming in an Ipython shell, so it enables me to execute certain lines of code without running the entire script.

The issue that occurs is that even after I have completely trained the model. I want to predict some values over some test data.
I run it once, and it shows me the Prediction and the Target, but if I run that code again (I am using Jupyter) it prints a wildly different value.
Sometimes printing negative values, or sometimes printing all of the predictions as 0.

Also to note, I learned TensorFlow from the Google Crash Course, which had some outdated code, but I updated some relevant code to newer standards.

I have also a Linear Regression model in my code, and it seems to be working fine. After training, I predict some values over some test data, and if I rerun that block of code it predicts the same values.

Also to note, both models say that they are running in a temporary directory, but only the linear regression model actually writes something in the specified temporary direction, while the DNN regression does not write anything at all, but trains appropriately (And even when specifying a `model_dir`, still doesn't write anything, so I assume it is the correct behavior?).

Training Code

```py
def train_dnn_regression_model(
    learning_rate,
    regularization_strength,
    steps,
    batch_size,
    hidden_units,
    feature_columns,
    training_examples,
    training_targets,
    validation_examples,
    validation_targets,
    ):

    periods = 10
    steps_per_period = steps / periods

    #Initialize DNN Regressor
    optimizer = tf.train.FtrlOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate, l1_regularization_strength=regularization_strength)
    optimizer = tf.contrib.estimator.clip_gradients_by_norm(optimizer, 5.0)
    dnn_regressor = tf.estimator.DNNRegressor(
        feature_columns=feature_columns,
        hidden_units=hidden_units,
        optimizer=optimizer,
        activation_fn=tf.nn.leaky_relu
    )

    #Training Functions
    training_input_fn = lambda: input_fn(
        training_examples,
        training_targets,
        batch_size=batch_size) 
    predict_training_input_fn = lambda: input_fn(
        training_examples, 
        training_targets, 
        num_epochs=1, 
        shuffle=False)

    #Validation Function
    predict_validation_input_fn = lambda: input_fn(
        validation_examples, 
        validation_targets, 
        num_epochs=1, 
        shuffle=False)

    #Train Model
    training_rmse = []
    validation_rmse = []

    print("Training Model")
    for period in range(0, periods):
        linear_regressor.train(
            input_fn=training_input_fn,
            #Manually break total steps by 10
            steps=steps_per_period
        )

        #Use Sklearn to calculate RMSE
        training_predictions = linear_regressor.predict(input_fn=predict_training_input_fn)
        training_predictions = np.array([item['predictions'][0] for item in training_predictions])
        training_root_mean_squared_error = math.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(training_predictions, training_targets))

        #Calculate Validation RMSE
        validation_predictions = linear_regressor.predict(input_fn=predict_validation_input_fn)
        validation_predictions = np.array([item['predictions'][0] for item in validation_predictions])
        validation_root_mean_squared_error = math.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(validation_predictions, validation_targets))

        #Append Losses
        training_rmse.append(training_root_mean_squared_error)
        validation_rmse.append(validation_root_mean_squared_error)

        print("Period:", period, "RMSE:", training_root_mean_squared_error)
    print("Training Finished")

    #Graph
    plt.ylabel("RMSE")
    plt.xlabel("Periods")
    plt.title("Root Mean Squared Error vs. Periods")
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.plot(training_rmse, label="training")
    plt.plot(validation_rmse, label="validation")
    plt.legend()

    return dnn_regressor
```

Print Predicted values, and Labels

```py
def test_regression_model(model, test_examples, test_targets):
    predict_test_input_fn = lambda: input_fn(
        test_examples, 
        test_targets, 
        num_epochs=1, 
        shuffle=False)

    test_predictions = model.predict(input_fn=predict_test_input_fn)
    test_predictions = np.array([item['predictions'][0] for item in test_predictions])

    for prediction, label in zip(test_predictions, test_targets): 
        print("Prediction:", prediction, "Label:", label, "Diff:", abs(prediction - label))

    return test_predictions
```

CODE THAT OUTPUTS VERY DIFFERENT RESULTS

```py
#DNN Regressor
test_predictions_dnn_regressor = test_regression_model(dnn_regressor, test_examples, test_targets)
test_rmse_dnn_regressor = math.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(test_predictions_dnn_regressor, test_targets))
print("Test RMSE:", test_rmse_dnn_regressor)
```

I expect to show some positive results, which is consistent over multiple executions of the code that is marked "CODE THAT OUTPUTS VERY DIFFERENT RESULTS" so that I can appropriately diagnose my model!

Comment: When you say execution, do you mean retraining the model as well? If so that is not so surprising because backpropagation is not deterministic.

Comment: Oh what I mean by "execution" is simply the code right below what I labeled "execution", I'll rewrite it so its more clear

Comment: Have you tried passing only ``test_examples`` to ``model.predict()``? I suspect ``input_fn`` is only used for training, and it could be updating your weights on each call.

Comment: `input_fn` is a template function what I have done is simply use it create all other relevant training/prediction functions as you can see here:`lambda: input_fn(
        test_examples, 
        test_targets, 
        num_epochs=1, 
        shuffle=False)` lambda just returns a function